# python script to access soft-body modifier ptcache (free, bake)

Tags: python, baking, cache

I have tried the following script to re-bake a soft-body modifier on a lattice object:

```
o =  bpy.data.objects['Lattice']
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = o
o.select_set(True)
with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=o):
    bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake()
    bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=True)
```

but get a context error on the free_bake() statement.   It appears to work for the bake_all() statement (I use the UI to delete the bake and comment out the free_bake().

Is there a more direct way to access an object.modifier...ptcache ?

(yes: i realize some of the above code statements are probably superfluous).

PS - I observe that almost all answers involving overrides are from deprecated versions of bpy, where override is an operator arg and override is a dictionary instead of keywords (with no examples of the keywords in the python documentation!).